# Do i need to start using SFP+ or is 1GBE sufficient from isp router to sonicwall?

Tags: networking, sfp

We are in the process of upgrading our leased fibre line from 100mbps to 300mbps, and are currently using cat6 1GBe to connect from the ISP provided Cisco router to our Sonicwall NSA3600 (and subsequently CAT 6 from the NSA to 5x Dell N3048 Switches).

Should i start replacing the cat 6 between the ISP Router, SonicWALL, and the main switches to SFP+ fibre connections, or will cat 6 still have enough bandwidth?

if cat 6 is still ok for the job, at what point would you upgrade to sfp+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should i start replacing the cat 6 between the ISP Router, SonicWALL,
>   and the main switches to SFP+ fibre connections, or will cat 6 still
>   have enough bandwidth?

No.

> if cat 6 is still ok for the job, at what point would you upgrade to
>   sfp+?

When you need to move >1Gbps (in reality I'd move to SFP+ when you're dealing with about 550-600Mbps but that's 'cos I'm a geek)

Comment: Brilliant, that's all i needed to know. Thank you.

Comment: Also note that the NSA 3600 is going to struggle to maintain throughput at rates near or above 1Gbps anyway